# Function to reiterate values in an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a function that inputs a new value into an empty array, and then the value stays in the array, even if the value changes. Let me explain with an example and I have so far:

```
var arr = [];
arr.unshift("f");
if (arr.length > 6) {
   arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);

arr.unshift("e");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);

arr.unshift("d");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);

arr.unshift("c");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);

arr.unshift("b");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);

arr.unshift("a");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);
arr.unshift("z");
if (arr.length > 6) {
  arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);
```

Here in the empty array a new value gets inputted in first position and stays in the array arr. This is what I get in the console:

```
(6) ["f"]    
(6) ["e", "f"]    
(6) ["d", "e", "f"]    
(6) ["c", "d", "e", "f"]    
(6) ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]    
(6) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]    
(6) ["z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

which is exactly what I want to achieve. Instead of these values I need a var that will get updated regularly.

```
var newValue = value_to_be_updated;

function myFunction(newValue) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.unshift(newValue);
    return arr
}

if (arr.length > 6) {
    arr.pop();
}
```

My goal is to reduce the above code and make it a function, but couldn't find anything helpful. Also is there any way the value inputted stays in the array, even if removed from the var?

Any help will be hugely appreciated!!!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your `if` condition inside the `function` itself, just before the `return`. Your code should work. Can you create a verifiable code snippet using `<>`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The function does its job, but if I change the newValue value the array doesn't "save" the value previously inserted (which is reasonable, since there is no code to "save" the previous value). I thought of the map() of forEach() methods, but they return a new array, still based on the previous array, so the values inserted from time to time don't get saved/stored.

Comment: It is unclear as to what you mean by *since there is no code to "save" the previous value*. Your `arr` is locally defined. Declare your arr outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the new value dynamically using for example a prompt, if you are expecting the value of `arr` to remain the same after changing the source code that would not work.
Still has @gurvinder372 said your function should look something like this

```
var arr = [];
function myFunction(newValue) {
  arr.unshift(newValue);
  if (arr.length > 6) {
    arr.pop();
  }
  return arr
}
```

then to use it you can do something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i<8; i++){
   var value = prompt('enter char');
   myFunction(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @wale your for loop reiterates the different values you enter on prompt, but once you load the page again the array gets reset. I modified your code like this: `var arr = [];
 function myFunction(newValue) {
  
  arr.unshift(newValue);
  
  if (arr.length > 6) {
   arr.pop();
  }
  return arr
 }
 
 console.log(arr);
 
 for (var i = 0; i<8; i++){
    var value = "t";
    myFunction(value);
 }`, as I don't need a prompt but will be modifying the value from time to time. And the for loop only reiterates the same value inserted 6 times.